# How to pull a list from Excel and use said list to search a dynamic website?

Tags: python, excel

Long story, short. I work for my local hardware store, and I'm trying to streamline and automate as much stuff as possible. As such, this is part of a larger project I'm trying to complete.

Like the title states, I'm trying to pull a list from an Excel file (a list of UPC barcodes). I want to then search each barcode on [www.truevalue.com](http://www.truevalue.com) using their search function; finally, I want to pull the SKU number from each result and put it into another Excel file with its corresponding UPC barcode. You may be thinking that our store rep would be willing to help us with getting this information, but corporate has been less than helpful.

I have spent days trying to figure this out; unfortunately, I went to school for biology, chemistry, and business rather than computer science. So this stuff is fairly new to me.

I've acquainted myself with Scrapy and Selenium in my attempt to figure this out. All the tutorials and FAQs I've read/watched show how to search for 1 individual item and pull information from the resulting page; consequently, I believe I could write code (in Python) that would accomplish that. However, I haven't been able to find any explanation for searching multiple products and then exporting the list of SKUs into an Excel file.

I guess I'm just kind of at a loss as to what module or function I would need to use to allow me to interface Excel with Selenium in this way. I'm not dead set on using Scrapy or Selenium. I'm willing to learn anything I need that would allow me to figure this out. So if you guys have a better idea, I'm game. Forgive me if I misused any technical terms, as I said, I am new to all of this. Thanks for taking your time to read, and I hope you guys can help!

Comment: There are several libraries for reading Excel data. Have you tried openpyxl or xlwings yet?

Comment: I do have openpyxl imported, and it appears to be excellent at manipulating Excel files. After reading through openpyxl's website, however, I wasn't able to find anything that would allow me to interface with Selenium in the way I described. That's not to say I didn't miss something. I'll check out xlwings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would write a simple script that uses openpyxl to read/write Excel sheets and scrape some sample data from a couple product pages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

url = 'https://www.truevalue.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
path = 'path to workbook'

# open Excel workbook and create product list
original_wb = load_workbook(filename = path + 'TrueValueUPCs.xlsx', data_only=True)
original_ws = original_wb['UPC Codes']
product_list = original_ws['A1':'A2']

# create new Excel workbook for writing and add headers
new_wb = Workbook()
new_ws = new_wb.active
row = ['Product Code', 'Brand', 'Name', 'Price']
new_ws.append(row)

# close select store popup
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"aside.locator-modal button.action-close"))).click()

for product in product_list:
    # search for product
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.header-content-right button[aria-label='Search']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"search"))).send_keys(product[0].value + "\n")

    # product page
    brand = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-info-wrapper div.brand > div.value"))).text
    name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-info-wrapper h1.page-title"))).text
    price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.price"))).text

    #write to Excel
    row = [product[0].value, brand, name, price]
    # print(row) # for debugging
    new_ws.append(row)

new_wb.save(path + 'output.xlsx')
driver.quit()
```

My output file looks like

| Product Code | Brand | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TV1010181 | MASTER MECHANIC | 1/2 In. Drive Ratcheting Breaker Bar | $52.99 |
| DCD780C2 | DEWALT | 20-Volt Compact Cordless Drill / Driver Kit, 1/2-In., 2 Lithium-Ion Batteries | $235.00 |

There are several things you will likely need/want to change.

1. `path` is the path on disk to your current Excel workbook, e.g. `path = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\'`
2. The name of the existing workbook, e.g. `'TrueValueUPCs.xlsx'`
3. The name of the sheet that contains the UPC codes, e.g. `'UPC Codes'`
4. The range of values to read, e.g. `'A1':'A2'`
5. The column titles aka header row
6. The name of the output file, e.g. `'output.xlsx'`

Comment: I've never used openpyxl before so there may be better ways to do some of this stuff but most is pulled from their docs so it should be at least decent... enough of a skeleton to get you started. Now you can customize it, add your own input sheet, change the format of the output sheet, scrape more/different data from the product page, etc.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to try this out?

Comment: So far, I've combined elements of your code plus the code I have already written. I have been working through it slowly, and it's coming along. Like I said, I'm pretty new to this :) I'm trying to get the CSS selectors to work for me right now because I need the SKU and model numbers. Thank you so much for your help! I'm sure I'll get it figured out given enough time. If not, I'll probably end up back here on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I got everything to work. One last question if you wouldn't mind. If I try to search for a UPC code that doesn't exist, it seems to crash the program. Is there a way to skip to the next UPC code when this happens? Maybe print "UPC not found" or something like that?

Comment: Sure. So the current script expects each UPC search to be successful so it goes right into scraping the product page. If you want to update the script to handle the case where the UPC is not found, you'll need to verify that we've actually landed on a product page. You can do that any number of ways... a couple that come to mind would be 1. check the URL and make sure it's not a search URL. 2. Look for the, "Sorry we couldn't find what you're looking for" text on the page. The search URL will probably be tricky due to timing issues.

Comment: I would just wait for the text to appear and put that in a `try-catch` and if you get a `TimeoutException` then you assume you are on a product page (because you aren't on a failed search page)... and then proceed from there.

Comment: If you give that a go and can't quite get it working, ask a new question with the new details and I or someone else will see it and try to help.

Answer (score 0):

[Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file) is a great resource for reading from an Excel spreadsheet. What you want to do is use the load_workbook() method to open your excel file, then read from the cells your info is located in and save all values into a single list or dictionary.

If you've found a method of scraping the data for *one* item, all you have to do is loop over your list/dictionary and perform the search/scrape for each item in your list, adding the result of each scrape to a second list as you go. Then, you can use openpyxl again to write the new data into the same or a separate spreadsheet.

Comment: Makes sense. I will definitely give this a shot once I get back to my work computer!